# Implementing pagination in DDD using data mappers

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, software

How should pagination be implemented in DDD with DataMappers? I thought about creating objects Range and Order and pass them to the find methods, but I don't know if that is a good solution since the pagination in this case is a matter of UI and performance and not a matter representing the model. I read about CQRS(http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) too, but the model that I'm working on dosen't look like it needs different models to represent Query and Command.

What do you guys think?

Comment: The same way you would implement pagination without DDD.  Pagination is not a business domain concern.  Find out how your chosen technology usually implements paging, and do that.

Comment: I agree with @RobertHarvey. I can't stretch my mind to see a way that DDD or CQRS has anything to do with decisions about pagination.

Comment: This question is quite similar to others on this site https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/261011/ddd-and-collections-and-paging-of-related-models

Comment: My spidey sense is tingling... what are you doing with the 'datamappers' exactly.....

Answer (score 3):

In general I would agree with @RobertHarvey and the answer above: if you have repository-like entities, just extend those to offer the support your UI needs.

However, your question is specifically:

> How should pagination be implemented in DDD with DataMappers?

If you truly want to model your problem in the business domain, you could consider a `Report` entity that offers some basic filtering, sorting, etc. A report is a common business entity. Most basic UI views in line-of-business systems can be thought of as simple reports, sometimes interactive.

How the report is formatted can then be thought of as either a UI problem, or a `ReportFormat` domain entity that is handled automatically by a smart UI. Depending on your situation, this could either be gross over-engineering or quite pragmatic. I have worked on systems, for example, where the whole UI was driven by SSRS.

If you are using C# the data selection aspect of a `Report` entity could be implemented as a LINQ expression tree that could be passed through to EF.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add some pagination objects that define the pagination data required.  For example, consider this C# code:

```
    public class OffsetPagination
    {
        public int PageNumber; //0
        public int RowsPerPage = 10;
    }

    public class KeySetPagination
    {
        public Int64 FirstKey = -1;
        public Int64 LastKey = -1;
        public Boolean Next = true;
        public int RowsPerPage = 10;
    }
```

Then just pass those in as part of your query object.  From there it is just a matter of writing queries to support pagination.  For example, consider this SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SampleOffsetPaging] 
    @PageNumber INT,
    @RowsPerPage INT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT [Id],[Name],[Created] from SampleTable
    ORDER BY Id
    OFFSET @PageNumber*@RowsPerPage ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY

END
```

Your client would keep track of what page it was on and pass that on as needed.  As @Robert has indicated, it doesn't effect your domain model at all as these would be used in the data layer to control queries.  It's just a small amount of additional information to manage the paging as part of your query.

I'm not sure what technology stack you are using but the concepts shown here can be applied in a similar fashion.